# JsonPath- filter on child level in swagger file

Tags: json, filter, jsonpath

Hi this is very short sample of my swagger file.
I want to find paths which has x-policy with peerName's value is social. I have tried many jsonpaths but all of them encountered errors. I tested in https://jsonpath.com
the final result must be {"/nzh/manage/contact/addContacts/","/nzh/biz/addProduct/","/nzh/subProductList/"}

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "paths": {
    "/nzh/manage/contact/addContacts/": {
      "put": {
        "tags": [
          "contact",
          "admin_operations"
        ],
        "summary": "",
        "operationId": "addContactsForAdmin",
        "x-policy": {
          "peerName": "social"
        }
      }
    },
    "/nzh/manage/customerClubProviderList/": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "admin_operations"
        ],
        "summary": "",
        "operationId": "getAuthorizedIpList_1"
      }
    },
    "/nzh/biz/transferToContact/": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "wallet"
        ],
        "summary": "",
        "operationId": "transferToContactByBusiness"
      }
    },
    "/nzh/biz/defineDiscountPercentageVoucherBrief/": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "voucher"
        ],
        "summary": "",
        "operationId": "defineDiscountPercentageVoucherBrief",
        "security": [
          {
            "semi-private": []
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/nzh/biz/addProduct/": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "market"
        ],
        "summary": "",
        "operationId": "addProduct",
        "x-policy": {
          "peerName": "social"
        }
      }
    },
    "/nzh/subProductList/": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "market"
        ],
        "summary": "",
        "operationId": "subProductList",
        "security": [
          {
            "public": []
          }
        ],
        "x-policy": {
          "peerName": "social"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the appropriate jsonPath that one of my colleagues found. I hope it will be helpful for others.

```
$.paths...x-policy[?(@ == 'social')]^^^^^~
```